# connect PostgreSql to Oracle live

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a PostgreSql database and I need to connect it to read data from oracle view and store that data in custom table

The PostgreSql database will connect to oracle everyday automatically to read the latest updates from oracle view

How to create it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you probably want a [SQL/MED *foreign data wrapper*](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers). Check out [`oracle_fdw`](http://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/). You could also use the generic `odbc_fdw` or `jdbc_fdw` wrappers via Oracle's ODBC or JDBC drivers.

Another option is DBI-Link.

Combine these with a cron job if you want to copy to a local view.